# Calculating the day of the week using Gauss Algorithm

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program which will calculate the same date in three different ways. I'm currently stuck on calculating the day of the week, as I need this to calculate the ISO week day. I've got an algorithm that I can use, and it is the one which I've got in my code, with the only difference being that the % sign in my code is replaced by the word "mod" in the algorithm.

When I run this, I get an error saying "Expected expression before % token". I've looked this up but didn't find any results. I've also tried to look at other ways of doing it, and found the Sakomoto Algorithm, but I don't exactly understand how that works. For a possible solution, I was thinking that I maybe need to create a function called mod, but I'm not entirely sure what I would need to put in there.

```
int day_of_the_week(int year)
{
int week_day;
week_day = %(1+5 * %(year - 1, 4) + 4 * %(year - 1, 100) + 6 * %(year-1, 
400), 7);
printf("The day of the week is %d\n", week_day);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like `mod` was a function in the other language. So `%(year - 1, 100)` becomes `(year - 1) % 100`, etc

Comment: You can't simply replace a function call with `%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gauss'

> R(1 + 5R(A - 1, 4) + 4R(A - 1, 100) + 6R(A - 1, 400), 7)

should be equivalent to

```
int week_day = (1 + 5 * (year - 1) % 4) + 4 * ((year - 1) % 100) + 6 * ((year - 1) % 400) % 7;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was just reading a link and figured out something similiar to this, minus some of the brackets that you included